# Convert Timespan data from CSV to KML

Tags: import, kml, google-earth, timespan

Working with GoogleEarth, I am able to import CSV data that contains long, lat, name, etc., but I am unable to get Google Earth Pro to recognize timespan (begin, end) information.

I found an online App called EarthPoint, that allows me to convert a CSV file into KML that includes the timespan data, but that app is limited in its ability to recognize additional fields.  Thus, I am unable to apply style templates to the EarthPoint imported data, as there is nothing for Google Earth to latch onto.

So I am looking for either a different app, that imports all three (geo, time, description), from either CSV, or straight from a spreadsheet app like Excel.

And barring the existence of such an app, I would simply like to know if there is a way to specify the headers so that Google Earth will reecognize the time series data for what it is.

Comment: Try also posting this on Google Earth help forum. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/maps/google-earth